# Initramfs error code 8 after booting to Windows on other hard drive

Tags: ubuntu, boot, grub, initramfs

I have multiple hard drives on my computer with different partitions, with different Windows installations and older (malfunctioning) Ubuntu versions.

When I change my hard drive boot priority in the BIOS-menu I enter a separate GRUB-bootloader in which I can boot to Windows 10. When reverting the BIOS boot priority, I get the correct GRUB-bootloader, but also an `initframfs error code 8` upon boot.

My active Ubuntu is installed on partition /dev/sdc6. After booting to a USB-installer and running:

```
sudo partprobe -s
```

I get the list of partitions, in which Ubuntu now resides on `/dev/sdd6`.
Is it possible to relocate these partitions to `/dev/sdc` again, or can I reconfigure the boot path in GRUB?

Additionally, how would I proceed to get Windows 10 visible to my current bootloader?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the relocation of your active Ubuntu from `/dev/sdc6` to `/dev/sdd6` is just a side effect of booting from a USB media. Any modern version of Ubuntu installs the bootloader in such a way that it identifies disks and filesystems by UUID, not by device name. That allows device names to change without interfering with booting.

If your BIOS boot order menu includes names of OSs and/or bootloaders like "Ubuntu" or "Windows Boot Manager", then your system is booting UEFI-style. In that case, please run `sudo efibootmgr -v` and `lsblk -o +PARTUUID` and edit the outputs into your original question. You should also be selecting the name of the OS you wish to boot, instead of just selecting the hard drive. Unlike BIOS, UEFI has been designed with understanding that a single computer and even a single disk may have multiple OSs installed to it. Unfortunately many firmware authors tend to hide this fact in an effort to make the firmware configuration as similar to old BIOS as possible.

"Error code 8" does not seem like a standard GRUB error message. It might be coming from initramfs, as a result of a filesystem check failure. This might indicate some kind of disk corruption, or perhaps that the system is trying to check/mount Windows filesystems, which can be problematic if Windows 10's **Fast Startup** feature is enabled. (Please describe the *exact* error message.)

Windows 10's Fast Startup stores a copy of the memory state of a freshly-started-up Windows 10 on disk similar to a hibernation image. Unfortunately this makes it impossible for the other operating systems to tell whether Windows 10 is really hibernated or just using Fast Startup. Changing the partitions belonging to a hibernated OS is a bad idea (because the hibernation image may include disk cache content that will become inconsistent with reality if partition contents are changed), and so Linux plays it safe and rejects attempts to mount/manipulate NTFS filesystems that contain an active hibernation image. The current recommendation is to disable Windows 10 Fast Startup on systems with multiple OSs, if you wish to access NTFS filesystems from the other OS.